# How to handle "if conditon" for variable?

Tags: c#, if-statement, windows-phone-8

The `var page` is what i gained from the user form the textbox. from that `var page` i done the below code.

hope you understand from the code, so i need not to explain more about this.

while i use the `page` for `if condition` below errors are shown. how to get rid of that ?

Code;

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
if (NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("Page"))
{
    var page = NavigationContext.QueryString["Page"];
    IsolatedStorageSettings settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
    if (!settings.Contains("qsPage"))
    {
        settings.Add("qsPage", page);
    }
    else
    {
        settings["qsPage"] = page;
    yourWebBrowser.Navigate(new Uri("/f" + page + ".html", UriKind.Relative));
}
}
```

code gives error;

```
private void def(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
int num = 0;    
var page = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["qsPage"];
if (int.TryParse(page, out num) && num > 0 && num < 455)
        {
// .... //
}
}
```

Error-

```
Error 1: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'object' to 'string'
Error 2: The best overloaded method match for 'int.TryParse(string, out int)' has some invalid arguments
```

Comment: You really don't need to force tags into your titles.  [Read this faq entry for more info, thanks.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var page = (string)IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["qsPage"];
```

Comment: works like a charm. thank you so much. ill mark it as answer in fourminutes

Answer (score 0):

```
var page = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["qsPage"] as string;

if (page != null && int.TryParse(page, out num) && num > 0 && num < 455)
...
```